# Is there a way to make getch() wait until a key is pressed?

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a project using ncursor to handle animation and user input. The thing is that I want `getchar()` to only ask for user input when the keyboard is actually pressed. I did find a function which is called `nodelay` but it for some reason didn't actually delay `getch()`.

My question is if there's a working alternative to this or if I might be using `nodelay` improperly. I've implemented `nodelay` into my code in this fashion:

```cpp
nodelay(win, true);

while (inGame == true)
{
    refresh();
    printPlayGround();
    wrefresh(win);
    key = getchar();
    setDirection(key);
    moveSnake();
}
```

The thing is that it still asks for user input even if I don't press the keyboard. Could threads instead be the solution to my problem?

Comment: Keyboard presses are an operating system thing.  You'll need to edit post with your OS information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after looking into more what ncurser input really is i found `wgetch(window variable)`. This is also probably why nodelay isn't working as i'm putting nodelay in one specific window but I'm using getch() on the "mainscreen". However while this does seemingly fix that issue, my code now only asks for user input once, while after that stopping to seemingly do it. But I've atleast come closer to getting it all working.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ detect keypress windows".  You can substitute "windows" with whatever your operating system is.